# How can I determine which collation variants a browser supports for Intl.Collator for languages which have multiple "alphabetic orders"?

Tags: javascript, sorting, internationalization, collation, ecmascript-intl

JavaScript ES6/Harmony now has language-specific sorting/collation.

Now browsers differ in their support so I'm finding with Chrome some languages I use work and other don't.

But what I'm having trouble with is for languages such as Finnish, Japanese, Spanish, and Swedish, which have more than one way of ordering text, finding which ways are supported by the browser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Intl.Collator.supportedLocalesOf` accepts a list of locales and returns the ones it supports, but it removes Unicode extensions from each locale before testing for support.  So if you were to do

```
Intl.Collator.supportedLocalesOf("de-u-co-phonebk")
```

and the `de` locale were supported but phonebook sorting were *not* supported, you'd get back `["de-u-co-phonebk"]`.  Likely worse (because I suspect support for the `de` locale will pretty much always imply support for phonebook sorting), if you *mistyped* that as

```
Intl.Collator.supportedLocalesOf("de-u-co-phonebm")
```

you'd get `["de-u-co-phonebm"]` which is potentially really bad.

Given that's out, I think what you have to do is individually attempt to create collators for all the locales, specifying all the possible Unicode locale extensions you care about that could affect sort order, then examine `resolvedOptions().locale` on the collator to see if the Unicode extension transferred over.  For example,

```
Intl.Collator("de-u-co-phonebk").resolvedOptions().locale
```

will return `"de-u-co-phonebk"`, while

```
Intl.Collator("de-u-co-phonebm").resolvedOptions().locale
```

will return `"de"`.